# Message not printing in terminal, after using serveroutput in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus

I have implemented the following trigger. The triggers gets fired, but the output is not displayed. I have checked the when I have enabled serveroutput (SET SERVEROUTPUT ON), after trigger is created. I am doing in this in SQLPLUS I haven't downloaded oracle.

The line "bye bye " will not print after I use the exit command.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_off
BEFORE LOGOFF ON SCHEMA when (user=USER)
BEGIN
--DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);

dbms_output.put_line('Bye bye');
END;
/
```

Please could you help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to read this:

> **Oracle documentation about DBMS_OUTPUT**
>
> The PUT Procedure and PUT_LINE Procedure in this package enable you to
> place information in a buffer that can be read by another trigger,
> procedure, or package. In a separate PL/SQL procedure or anonymous
> block, you can display the buffered information by calling the
> GET_LINE Procedure and GET_LINES Procedure.
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_output.htm

SQL*Plus and all other developer tools implicitly call `dbms_output.get_line` after executing any piece of code, that's why you can see output on your screen. Also, you can call `dbms_output.get_line` only after your code had finished execution, in your case - after trigger execution, and, as result, after logout. But after logout you can't do anything - session is closed. So, you will never see this "last goodbye". Instead of that, you can create log table and insert your "bye bye" there.